# Am I misunderstanding React Native's TextInput multiline and numberOfLines properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a TextInput that would have a height of 4 rows of text and would not grow over that height if there are 5 or more rows of text, and instead it would be scrollable. I assumed that using TextInput's multiline and numberOfLines properties like this would work, but alas when I reach row 5, the textBox just becomes bigger.

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Take note of anything contributing to your mood"
    maxLength={250}
    multiline={true}
    numberOfLines={4}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give lineHeight and maxHeight property to TextInput style
i.e maxHeight should be in proportion to lineHeight,

if lineHeight is 20, maxHeight should be 100 if you want to restrict text box for 4 lines

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("Useless");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
        multiline={true}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    maxHeight: 100,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    lineHeight: 20,
  },
});
```